# Ruby Error: "no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String"

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner with Ruby, practicing looping and if statements.

I went a little off track with my course work, and tried to run the following code:

```
puts("Enter your age!")
age = gets.to_i
again = "Try again!"

while age <= 100 

if age == 0 
  puts("You are very very young. " + again)
  age = gets.to_i

elsif age >= 1 && age <= 5
  puts("You are quite small. Though you are breathing, you may not    understand this. " + again)
  age = gets.to_i
else 
  puts("You are a capable of reading " + again)
  age = gets.to_i
end 
end 
puts("Your age," + age + " is a good one")
```

When I run it, I am prompted to enter an age. 
If the age I enter <= 100 everything works according to the code.
If not, I get the error:

> rehearsal.rb:20:in `+': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
>   (TypeError) from rehearsal.rb:20:in`'

Other StackOverflow answers (solving this error message) I read suggested that the error was in misusing the "to_i" method. I made sure to include it, and my error is still here.

Where is my bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, the `+` method for adding strings doesn't work on integers. In your example, the `age` variable is an integer. This might seem a little strange if you are used to working with JavaScript.

You need to use `string interpolation`

```
puts("Your age, #{age} is a good one")
```

This works.

Comment: It worked, with an added quotation mark at the end of the line. Thanks again!